# Valid metric on a hyperbolic space

Tags: metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry

*Note: cross-posted to [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324595/valid-metric-on-a-hyperbolic-space)*

I'm looking at the distance that's defined in [this paper on Poincaré Embeddings](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7213-poincare-embeddings-for-learning-hierarchical-representations.pdf):

$d(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}) = \operatorname{arccosh} \left(1 + 2\frac{\left\| \mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v} \right\|^2}{(1 - \left\| \mathbf{u} \right\|^2)(1 - \left\| \mathbf{v} \right\|^2)} \right)$

for $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v} \in \mathcal{B}^d$ using the Poincaré ball model of hyperbolic space.

Does this define a valid metric? It's easy to see that

- $d(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}) \geq 0$ since $\left\| \mathbf{u} \right\| \leq 1$ and $\left\| \mathbf{v} \right\| \leq 1$ and so the rhs inside the parentheses is positive ($\operatorname{arccosh}(x)$ is an increasing function for $x \geq 0$),
- $\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{v}$, then $d(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}) = 0$, and
- $d(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}) = d(\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{u})$

However I'm having a hard time trying to prove the triangle inequality in this case. I've tried using the logarithmic form but that didn't get me anywhere. I also found the identity ${\displaystyle \operatorname {arcosh} u\pm \operatorname {arcosh} v=\operatorname {arcosh} \left(uv\pm {\sqrt {(u^{2}-1)(v^{2}-1)}}\right)}$ under "Addition Formulae (sic.)" [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Inverse_hyperbolic_cosine) but that also seemed to be a dead end. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I don't understand. If $u=v$ then the hyperbolic distance is zero and $f$ equal $1$

Comment: sorry should have been the original function $d$ - have updated the question